# Stream data from C++ to Python

Tags: python, c++, stream

I'm running a simulation using C++ and in every time-step I log current metrics. I want to create seperate Python script which has a live-plot of those metrics. Therefore I need to get the metric data from C++ to the Python script while the simulation is running. What's the best and fastest solution to do so?
My first thought was simply to update a JSON file in C++ and then have the live-plot function read the JSON file every iteration. But that sounds like it will slow down both the simulation and the live-plot.
I also thought about sending the data via sockets with the C++ program as the client and the Python script as the server but that seemed too complex and tedious.

Which is the best way to solve this?

Comment: Sockets are quite commonly used - they are not *that* tedious. The most efficient way is probably to write a Python module using the Python API

Comment: "best" is purely subjective

Comment: You could just  append a JSON to a text file. Then, your script would read line by line on the same file (every update in a new line). It would be like a file-backed message queue (you could also use a message queue, btw).

Comment: Named Pipe may be used for IPC.